# Multiple Spring profiles and Maven profiles in one war

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I got parser Spring Batch sheduled jobs. I got many jobs and here are just two of them:

```
@Profile("eodT0")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class JobConfigurationEodT0 { ... }

@Profile("eodRepo")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
public class JobConfigurationEodRepo { ... }
```

My application.yml config:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: @activatedProperties@
```

And pom.xml:
Some profiles from big list of them:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>eodT0</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>eodT0</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>eodRepo</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>eodRepo</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I want it to be like

spring:
  profiles.active: eodT0, eodRepo instead of @activatedProperties@

If I check more than one maven profile only one will work. I need to check profiles depending on what jobs I want to do to make them all active to make war and put it on server. How is it to be done?

Comment: Why do you need maven profiles? Can you describe the use case for what purpose you need them related with spring-boot?

Comment: I'm making it for idea's users who just can use gui and make jar/war without using code. I'm trying to do it to work automaticaly for them. It's a bit strange I know but still need to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass it as a system property.

```
mvn package -DactivatedProperties=eodT0,eodT1
```